# excel vba code password protected would not disappear

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I have opened an excel file containing VBA password protected (not belonging to me) and from that moment on what happens is that the code remains in the VBA editor even if I close ALL the files (see atteched pic)

Such filed was called treelist and in the VBA editor "solver.XLMA"

Put in other words. Whatever excel of mine I opened now with or without vba code once I click "editor" the first thing I see is that "solver.XLMA" that I can not access nor delete. It is really anoying because I dont know what this code is doing.
(note: yes, I closed excel several times and opened it again. solver.xlma was still there)

As you see in the picture the "solver.xlma" stais even if I close all the excel workbooks.

Some idea of how can I get rid of it and what is going on here?

thx

[image]

Comment: That's the `Solver` Add-In. Go to File > Options > Add-Ins, then click Go beside "Manage Excel Add-ins". Uncheck the Solver Add-in and hit Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a solver add-in. To turn it off:

1. Click the **File** tab, click **Options**, and then click the
   **Add-Ins** category.
2. In the Manage box, click **Excel Add-ins**, and then click **Go**. The Add-Ins dialog box appears.
3. In the Add-Ins available box, clear the check box next to the add-in that you want
   to deactivade (Solver), and then click **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:
That's the Solver Add-In. Go to File > Options > Add-Ins, then click Go beside "Manage Excel Add-ins". Uncheck the Solver Add-in and hit Ok